# Is is possible to apply secondary axis for only one set of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following graph to be processed:
[image]

I've added a secondary axis to this graph, the exposure and hedged value for USD is 2.0 and 1.5, respectively.

My goal is to apply the secondary axis to the values of USD, and make the value of USD looks less trivial.

However, it looks like I can only select "Exposure" and "Hedged" rather than "CHF", "EUR" and "USD":

[image]

After done some research, it seems there is no official way to do it. I am using Office 2016 Pro Plus, is there any idea of this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot the USD data points on the secondary axis, but you must ensure that the chart communicates that clearly, so the reader can see that the scale for USD is different. You could use data labels for that.

To get the USD data onto the secondary axis, you need a data layout where these data points can be isolated into their own series. The screenshot shows how it can be done.

I have selected a different color intensity for the data on the secondary axis, and also used data labels to point out the values.

[image]

Select the cells from A1 to D5, insert a clustered column chart. Excel will plot column A on the X axis, so click "Switch Row/Column" on the chart ribbon.

Then change the series chart type and send the two US series to the secondary axis. Decrease the gap width for all data series and add data labels for the US series.